# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.TempData.get returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, tempdata

below the error `msg`.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.TempData.get returned null.
```

I'm getting this error while:

```
TempData["test"] = "test"; //this is for testing
TempData["test"] = someObj; //this is my aim, but I'm getting the same error
```

I do not know if it matters, but I run constructor of class that is a controller and then method by reflection (`method.Invoke(instanceConstructor, new object[] { colums });`). During logic in that method I'm trying to use `TempData`

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            //options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true; //this option my startup dosent know what it is. even if I copy/paste using's from github example, I just added those to the topic
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc() //.AddSessionStateTempDataProvider(); I tried with and without
        services.AddSession();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) //, IHostingEnvironment env
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
      }
}
```

it's funny because in another controller the `TempData` works fine. I checked the `usings` from those controllers and those `usings` are the same.

`TempData` is working with `ProductController` for string types `TempData["message"] = $"'{deletedProduct.Name}' - produkt został usunięty";`

it's working without `app.UseCookiePolicy();` too in `ProductController`

I found some topic which redirect me to msdn with tips to add `app.UseCookiePolicy();` and `options to cokies` but like I said it doesn't worked for me

I'm using core 2.0

Please explain why `TempData` does not work properly or help in finding an error in my application

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know if it matters, but I run constructor of class that is a
>   controller and then method by reflection
>   (method.Invoke(instanceConstructor, new object[] { colums });). During
>   logic in that method I'm trying to use TempData

it has matter! - Session and tempdata dosent work at invoked methods by reflection.